# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, when using dropzone

Tags: cors, dropzone.js

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, X-Requested-With, Cache-Control, X-File-Name
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

This is part of the response header if I sent `post` request to the same url using ajax manually.

But when `Dropzone` sent requests, there were no these lines in the response header.
The error I got:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.114:8080/api/files.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.114' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Any idea how to fix this?

Part of the request header of `Dropzone`:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.4,zh;q=0.2,zh-TW;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:cache-control, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
```

Comment: did you use any browser plugins that make this happen?

Comment: @Chiu no browser plugins

Answer (score 0):

Setting Cache-Control header solved the problem.
Moreover you are not allowed to use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.

```
dropzoneConfig: DropzoneConfigInterface = {
    url: your_url
    method: "POST",
    withCredentials: false,
    headers: {
      "Cache-Control": "",
    }
  };
```